# EmberJS: toggleProperty set all properties of a Component to a default value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I'm trying to implement nested components in Ember 2.0.1, but I'm getting a strange behavior when use `toggleProperty` function inside of the action handler.

The first component looks like:

```
// ./components/comp-1.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  prop1: false,
  hello: "Default text of comp-1",

  _changeHello: function() {
    this.set('hello', 'Text set by comp-1');
  }.on("init"),

  actions: {
    customAction1() {
      this.toggleProperty('prop1');
    }
  }
});
```

.

```
// ./templates/components/comp-1.hbs
<button {{action 'customAction1'}}>{{hello}}</button>
```

The second one is:

```
// ./components/comp-2.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  data: [],

  _doSomeImportentStuff: function() {
    var data = this.get('data');

    data = [{name: 'Text set by comp-2', bool: false}, 
            {name: 'Text set by comp-2', bool: true}];

    this.set('data', data);
  }.on("init")
});
```

.

```
// ./templates/components/comp-2.hbs
{{#each data as |d|}}
{{comp-1 hello=d.name prop1=d.bool}}
{{/each}}
```

The component `comp-2` creates two buttons with names *Text set by comp-**1***. If I click on a button the text changes to *Text set by comp-**2*** because of the execution of the function `this.toggleProperty('prop1')` that is called in the action handler `customAction1`. If I remove this function or remove the setting of `prop1` from `./templates/components/comp-2.hbs` then everything works as expected, i.e. text of the buttons stays always as *Text set by comp-**1***.

Why does `toggleProperty` function set back other properties?

Am I doing something wrong?

The behavior in action can be seen here: http://ember-twiddle.com/90798b4952deb4a83de1

Comment: any success with this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're creating a bug by binding two different pieces of data to the same property on `init`. You're setting `comp-1`'s `hello` to `Text set by comp-1`on `comp-1`'s `init`, and also binding it to `d.name` on `comp-2`'s `init`.

You might expect the value of `hello` to just settle on whatever was last and then work as expected from there, but you're running into one of the problems with two-way data binding and drawing a good example of why the Ember community is moving away from two-way bindings and embracing [DDAU](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/).

I assume this is just something you stumbled upon, as I can't imagine this exact case occurring in the wild, but just in case, use `Ember.computed.oneWay`:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  prop1: false,
  readOnlyHello: Ember.computed.oneWay('hello'),

  _changeHello: function() {
    this.set('readOnlyHello', 'Text set by comp-1');
  }.on("init"),

  actions: {
    customAction1() {
      this.toggleProperty('prop1');
    }
  }
});
```

Then use `{{readOnlyHello}}` instead of `{{hello}}` inside of `comp-1`'s template.

If you needed to toggle `d.bool` in `comp-2` with a button that is in `comp-1`, you should follow DDAU here as well. You would send an action up to `comp-2` and let `comp-2` perform the toggle.